# Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) Vanishing gradient problem - Why does it affect earlier timesteps more?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation, derivative

I understand the concept of backpropagation in standard neural networks and  backpropagation through time with RNNs, why this causes exponentially smaller gradients at earlier time steps and most of the maths behind it all, but what I don’t understand is why this affects the earlier timestep in particular? Since, the parameters (weights) in the RNN are all shared between timesteps, why is it that the earlier timestep is more affected? Wouldn’t they all be affected since they all share the same badly optimized weight which is never updated due to the many small terms in the multiplicative product which produces $\frac{\partial E}{\partial w} $? I feel like I'm totally misunderstanding something here. Many thanks

Comment: The problem is that earlier steps can't contribute as much to $\frac{\partial E}{\partial w}$. By the product rule, all of the time steps' contributions are added together to compute that gradient, but the amount from the earlier steps is, as you note, exponentially shrunken.

Comment: Does this apply to every parameter w in the RNN - are they all calculated in this manner as a sum from the product rule, or is it only specific parameters which are calculated in this way?